# Magento 2 Admin Form Shows Blank Page

Tags: magento2

I am building a backend page to create items in the database.
My admin form page shows up but only with the title below. No form elements, Here is the code:

*Here is the code Vendor\Events\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Addevent*

```
namespace Vendor\Events\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;


class Addevent extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Vendor Create an Event')));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

}

*View/Adminhtml/layout/vendor_events_addevent.xml*

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="vendor_events_addevent_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

*View/Adminhtml/ui_component/vendor_events_addevent_listing.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_events.vendor_events_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_events.vendor_events_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">employee_form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="employee_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">woodmizer_events_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">pri_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">pri_id</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset name="employee_details">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="employee_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Id</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file names are wrong. Your controller is `Vendor\Events\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Addevent` and in your `etc/adminhtml` folder you should have a `routes.xml` which tells Magento where the module resources are.

When Magento creates the URLs for these pages, it's looking for `<route>/<folder>/<file>` which in your case is `<whatever your route is>/post/addevent`. Your layout needs to be named `<whatever your route is>_post_addevent.xml` and the UI component `<whatever your route is>_addevent_listing.xml`. You'll need to replace `<whatever your route is>` accordingly. Then as long as your models and di.xml are as they should be, (I assume they are). You can then rerun the main Magento commands and you should have a page you can view in the admin.

Magento commands wise, I would usually use `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile` just to be on the safe side. Make sure you update the path in your layout file to match the one you use for the UI component.